# Ajax request to restful api from different domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a restful api that works normally when i am calling from the postman. On postman i am giving the following configuration to get answer: 
-POST: "https://www.example.net/API/MyFunction"
I have no authorization.
-Headers: 
Content-Type : application/json,
username:myusername,
password:mypassword
-Body
raw

```
{"firstparameter":"firtparameter_value"}
```

I have a pure html domain where i would like to make some calls and provide data from this api. So i added a link to the jquery-3.3.1.js and create an ajax call. I tried to follow this guide https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/  but when i run the call i am getting the bellow error.
Ajax call:

```
 var username = 'myusername';
 var password = 'mypassword';
$.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "jsonp",

    url: 'https://www.example.net/API/MyFunction',


    contentType: 'text/plain',
    crossDomain: true,
    data:{"firstparameter":"firtparameter_value"},
    xhrFields: {

        withCredentials: false
    },

    headers: {


        username: username,
        password: password
    },

    success: function () {


    error: function () {

    }
});
```

the error i am geting is :

> GET
>   https://www.example.net/API/MyFunction/?callback=jQuery33104247946565223606_1541427224545&firstparameter=firtparameter_value&_=1541427224546
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to set the dataType to `jsonp` and not `json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> type: 'POST',
> dataType: "jsonp",
> ```

JSONP requests work by injecting a `<script src>` element which makes a GET request. The method property is ignored by jQuery when you use JSONP.

You **cannot** make a POST request with JSONP.

A REST API is unlikely to return JSONP (which was a hack to work around the Same Origin Policy in the bad old days before we had [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068) — and, like CORS, it must be set up on the *server*). Your API certainly does not because it is telling you the GET method (required for JSONP) is not allowed.

Set the correct value for `dataType`.

---

You have some other problems, but they are not related to the error message.

You said "`-Headers: Content-Type : application/json`" but then in the JS "`contentType: 'text/plain'`" — use the correct content-type.

You said "`data:{"firstparameter":"firtparameter_value"}`" but jQuery will encode that in URL format not JSON format. You need to explicitly encode it as JSON with `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: This is what I was wondering when I noticed the `jsonp` header. Appreciate the articulation, personally.

Comment: i have edit my json call and put the bellow values: type: 'POST',
  dataType: "json", contentType: 'application/json',data:JSON.stringify({"firstparameter":"firtparameter_value"}) and i get two errors 1)405 (Method Not Allowed) and 2)has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @user2340890 the second one potentially indicates that you haven't set up your server to allow CORS requests. Difficult to know, without seeing the API server code

Comment: @user2340890 — So now you're making a preflight OPTIONS request which is being rejected. So the problem you were asking about is solved, and your new problem is covered by [this link from my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068)

Answer (score 0):

That error happens whenever you try to call an API function with the wrong Method, for example call a POST function with a Get Ajax call.

You need to be sure that your backend has the method your calling from ajax as POST